# How to get latest 5 posts from website and show that into view flow?

Tags: android

Please help me in this how to get latest 5 posts from website and show that into view flow? like shown in the image . You can find image on the following url [click here for image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ReTuf7_jtWTFRCd2hyY181N2c/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a design.

Comment: @nalply but i also want to know how to get a post from the website to viewFlow

Comment: can anyone tell me how to get blog post from website to ViewFlow?i want to get latest five posts and to set them in ViewFlow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We Androidience called it as ViewFlow:

[You can find example here done by pakerfeldt](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow)